# How to find the long range transition matrix L of P

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

P is the transition matrix of a regular Markov chain. Find the long range transition matrix L of P.
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4\\1/2&1/2 &1/4\\0 &1/4 & 1/2\end{bmatrix}$$

I found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = 1/4.$ Which means P is a transition matrix.

I am not sure how to go on with this question after this. Finding the eigenspace for $\lambda = 1$ gives me  $ v = \begin{bmatrix} 1.5 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ but I can't see how to turn that into a steady-state vector.

Comment: Your steady-state vector should be a probability vector. So you can try by normalizing what you have found so that the entries sum to 1.